# Compile and deploy ruby on VSTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devops

Can't get ruby sample web application in Visual Studio to work on Azure Cloud https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/gitquickstart.
Push to visual studio team services (VSTS) git. The code to be compiled by ci build provided by VSTS, this is allocated randomly by vsts on azure cloud. And once compilation done the deployment should happen the same azure Linux vm which I'd mention in the question.

Environment: Ubuntu 16, ruby 2.2.5, rails 5.

Now I want to build it using hosted build agent through SSH task for build and deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, just use the BASH for this, don't use the GUI on the portal and you'll do just fine; Some trigger is not activating in the back in order for the service to start;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17854823)

Comment: If I`m new here, that doesn't mean I have no skill...but I guess things work differently around here;